# Element-wise power using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, elementwise-operations

I am currently reading [this book](https://books.google.de/books?id=LPm3DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=iterator%20plane%20opencv&source=bl&ots=2vHrXddfz9&sig=DW0xnwrOJZTz4oi-8WzF487j8qA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj85burj6PXAhUQJlAKHUp0B1YQ6AEINzAC#v=onepage&q=iterator%20plane%20opencv&f=false). The author wrote a code snippet on page 83 in order to (if i understand it correctly) calculate the element-wise power of two matrices. But i think the code doesn't fulfill its purpose because the matrix `dst` does not contain the element-wise power after the execution.

Here is the original code:

```
const Mat* arrays[] = { src1, src2, dst, 0 };
float* ptrs[3];

NAryMatIterator it(arrays, (uchar**)ptrs);
for( size_t i = 0; i < it.nplanes; i++, ++it )
{
    for( size_t j = 0; j < it.size; j++ )
    {
        ptrs[2][j] = std::pow(ptrs[0][j], ptrs[1][j]);
    }
}
```

Since the parameter of the constructor or `cv::NAryMatIterator` is `const cv::Mat **`, i think change of values in the matrix `dst` is not allowed.

I tried to assign `ptrs[2][j]` back in `dst` but failed to get the correct indices of `dst`. My questions are as follows:

1. Is there a convenient method for the matrix element-wise power, like `A .^ B` in Matlab?
2. Is there a way to use `cv::NAryMatIterator` to achieve this goal? If no, then what is the most efficient way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this working by converting the `src1`, `src2` and `dst` to `float (CV_32F)` type matrices. This is because the code treats them that way in `float* ptrs[3];`.

An alternative implementation using `opencv` functions `log`, `multiply` and `exp` is given at the end.

As an example for your 2nd question,

```
Mat src1 = (Mat_<int>(3, 3) <<
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    7, 8, 9);
Mat src2 = (Mat_<uchar>(3, 3) <<
    1, 2, 3,
    1, 2, 3,
    1, 2, 3);
Mat dst = (Mat_<float>(3, 3) <<
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    7, 8, 9);

src1.convertTo(src1, CV_32F);
src2.convertTo(src2, CV_32F);

cout << "before\n";
cout << dst << endl;

const Mat* arrays[] = { &src1, &src2, &dst, 0 };
float* ptrs[3];
NAryMatIterator it(arrays, (uchar**)ptrs);
for( size_t i = 0; i < it.nplanes; i++, ++it )
{
    for( size_t j = 0; j < it.size; j++ )
    {
        ptrs[2][j] = std::pow(ptrs[0][j], ptrs[1][j]);
    }
}

cout << "after\n";
cout << dst << endl;
```

outputs

```
before
[1, 2, 3;
  4, 5, 6;
  7, 8, 9]
after
[1, 4, 27;
  4, 25, 216;
  7, 64, 729]
```

If you remove the `src1.convertTo(src1, CV_32F);` or `src2.convertTo(src2, CV_32F);`, you won't get the desired result. Try it.

If this is a separate function, don't place the `convertTo` within the function, as it modifies the image representation, that could affect later operations. Instead, use `convertTo` on temporary Mats, like

```
Mat src132f, src232f, dst32f;
src1.convertTo(src132f, CV_32F);
src2.convertTo(src132f, CV_32F);
dst.convertTo(dst32f, CV_32F);

pow_mat(&src132f, &src232f, &dst32f); /* or whatever the name */
```

As for your first question, I'm not aware of such function. But you can try something like

```
Mat tmp;
cv::log(src1, tmp);
cv::multiply(src2, tmp, dst);
cv::exp(dst, dst);
```

using the relation that `c = a^b` is equivalent to `c = e^(b.ln(a))`. Here, the matrices should have type `32F` or `64F`. This produces

```
[1, 4, 27.000002;
  4, 25.000002, 216.00002;
  6.9999995, 64, 729.00006]
```

for the example above.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer. In your first code block, it turns out that the `ptrs[2]` works as a proxy of the matrix `dst`. I can assign values to `dst` by assigning values to `ptrs[2][i]`, right? And i tried to let `cdecl` explain `const int ** i`. The output was: `declare i as pointer to pointer to const int`. Does it mean that i cannot change the matrix value directly, but can assign values to it through the proxy?

Comment: @ShihaoXu You are correct. My statement about const was flawed so I removed it. As an example, you can try something like `const Mat *p[] = {&src1}; p[0] = &dst;    /* okay */ p[0]->at<float>(1, 1) = 10;    /* wrong */ p[0]->data[0] = 11;    /* okay */`

Comment: Got the point :D. btw the `c = e^(b.ln(a))` trick is really fantastic.